# Void Insert/List not working - C

Tags: c

When I insert 2 or more persons in the program, when I try to list the results, I only get the name of the second person I inserted.

I would like to insert as many persons as possible, and list all the namoes and properties .. then I would like to do the average age for the house I'm serching.

This is my insert/list code :

```
void inserir()
{
  FILE *fCasa; //Apontador para ficheiro
  fCasa = fopen(NomeFicheiro, "rb+");
  if (fCasa == 0) {
    fCasa = fopen(NomeFicheiro, "wb");
    fclose(fCasa);
    fCasa = fopen(NomeFicheiro, "rb+");
  }
  //Ficheiro aberto e pronto para ler/escrever

  struct defCasa Casa;
  int C = 0;
  int C1 = 0;
  printf("\nNumero da Porta:");
  scanf("%d",&Casa.NumeroPorta);
  printf("Numero de Pessoas:");
  scanf("%d",&Casa.NumeroPessoas);
  C = Casa.NumeroPessoas;
  while (C1 != C) {
    C1++;
    printf("Nome da %da Pessoa:", C1);
    scanf("%s",Casa.NomePessoas);
    printf("Idade da Pessoa:");
    scanf("%d",Casa.Idade);

  }
  printf("Contacto da casa:");
  scanf("%d",&Casa.NumTlm);

  Casa.estado = 1;
  fseek(fCasa, 0, SEEK_END);
  fwrite(&Casa, 1, sizeof(struct defCasa), fCasa);
  fclose(fCasa);
}


void listar ()
{
  int C = 0;
  int C1 = 0;
  int NrRegistos = 0;
  int AcumuladoPessoas = 0;
  FILE *fLer;
  fLer = fopen(NomeFicheiro, "rb+");
  if (fLer != 0) {
    struct defCasa Armazena;
    fseek(fLer, 0,SEEK_SET);
    while (fread(&Armazena, 1, sizeof (struct defCasa), fLer) != 0) {
      if (Armazena.estado == 1) {
        printf("Na Casa %d moram %d pessoas\n", Armazena.NumeroPorta,Armazena.NumeroPessoas);
        C = Armazena.NumeroPessoas;
        C1 = 0;
        while (C1 != C) {
          C1++;
          printf("Constituintes da familia: %s\n",Armazena.NomePessoas);
        }
        printf("Contactos:%d",Armazena.NumTlm);
        NrRegistos++;
        AcumuladoPessoas += Armazena.MaximoNumeroPessoas;
      }
    }

    fclose(fLer);
    if (NrRegistos > 0) {
      printf("\nA media de idades e: %f\n", (float)AcumuladoPessoas/NrRegistos);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty huge chunk of code for us to work through and find problems. One thing you might want to do is break that up into smaller chunks, functions that have a more specific responsibility, so you can test those individually and ensure they're all working correctly before combining them into this huge thing.

Comment: If you want to be able to have more than 1 person, you are going to need to use an array or equivalent.

Comment: Ok, the thing is that i insert, list, but i get that lil bit problem of showing only the second name inserted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `inserir`, you let the user enter several dates in a loop `while (C1 != C) { ...`, but you store each input in the same data member of your struct.
So as you always write into the same place, the second input overrides the first one.

I suppose this data member `Casa.NomePessoas` should be an array of strings rather than a single string, such that you can write, for example, `scanf("%s",Casa.NomePessoas[C1])`; The same applies to `Casa.Idade`, of course.